# «581 гектар озимого ячменя убран»?

Tags: выбор-слов, числительные

> 581 гектар озимого ячменя убран.

Верно ли согласование подлежащего?

Answer (score 1):

[§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

> При составных числительных, оканчивающихся на один, сказуемое, как правило, ставится в форме единственного числа, например: Двадцать один делегат прибыл на совещание; ...было подано сразу тридцать одно заявление (Шолохов). Форма множественного числа данной конструкции может быть обусловлена контекстом, например: Двадцать один делегат встретились за круглым столом (сказуемое-глагол встретились указывает на взаимное действие, которое выражается формой множественного числа); Двадцать один ящик с посудой, которые были доставлены на базу, попали туда по ошибке (влияние придаточного предложения с союзным словом которые в форме множественного числа); **За все уплачено 231 рубль** (при формальной роли подлежащего счетный оборот имеет значение обстоятельства меры в страдательной конструкции); Двадцать один студент не явились на экзамен (эмоционально окрашенный разговорный вариант, подчеркивающий количество отсутствовавших).

Я бы написал: **Убрано 581 гектар озимого ячменя** (подобно примеру с рублями).

Дополнение. Непонятно, почему выбран столь странный порядок слов (сравните: почему столь странный порядок слов выбран).

Comment: т.е убран - это ошибка?

Comment: Думаю, не является ошибкой ни один из трех вариантов. Лучше "убрано". "Убран" — допустимо, "убраны" — коряво. Но порядок слов тоже играет роль. "581 гектар озимого ячменя убрано" - плохо, "убрано 581 гектар озимого ячменя" - хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

**Убран 581 гектар озимого ячменя. Убрано 500 гектаров озимого ячменя.**

Вариант "убрано 581 гектар озимого ячменя" имеет нежелательное сочетание с ед. числом "гектар".

Глагол ***убрать*** (собрать после созревания) может относиться **к урожаю или к площадям, с которых снимается урожай.** Поэтому можно сказать:  (1) убран озимый  ячмень с 581 гектара. (2) убран (очищен)  581 гектар озимого ячменя.

**УБРАТЬ**, св. 1. что. Собрать после созревания (о полевых культурах, урожае). У. хлеб, зерновые, огородные культуры. Надо у. урожай до наступления холодов. Хлеба в некоторых районах ещё не убраны. Убрано сто гектаров посевных площадей (на ста гектарах снят урожай). Поля ещё не убраны (с них ещё не снят урожай).

Comment: "Нежелательное сочетание с ед. ч. (гектар)". А как же у Розенталя сочетание с  ед. ч. (рубль): **За все уплачено 231 рубль** (см. выше)?

Comment: И здесь сочетание не из лучших, но как тогда сказать? За все уплачен 231 рубль? Как-то не по русски, уж лучше "за всё уплачена сумма, равная 231 рублю".  А убран (очищен) 231 гектар звучит нормально.